# Put two Tikz Pictures in Adjacently Opposite Boxes A Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have two `tikz` pictures as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]%use thistoresize tikzpicture
            
            \draw[|-|] (90.0:2.8) arc(90.0:67.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:2.8) arc(67.5:45.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:2.8) arc(45.0:22.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (22.5:2.8) arc(22.5:00.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (00.0:2.8) arc(00.0:-22.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-22.5:2.8) arc(-22.5:-45.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-45.0:2.8) arc(-45.0:-67.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-67.5:2.8) arc(-67.5:-90.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-90.0:2.8) arc(-90.0:-112.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-112.5:2.8) arc(-112.5:-135.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-135.0:2.8) arc(-135.0:-157.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-157.5:2.8) arc(-157.5:-180.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-180.0:2.8) arc(-180.0:-202.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-202.5:2.8) arc(-202.5:-225.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-225.0:2.8) arc(-225.0:-247.5:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-247.5:2.8) arc(-247.5:-270.0:2.8) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
            %%% 
            \draw[|-|] (90:3.4) arc(90:00.0:3.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.8) arc(67.5:-22.5:3.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:4.2) arc(45.0:-45.0:4.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$}; 
            %\draw[|-|] (0:3.8) arc(0:-90:3.8) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_3$}; 
            \draw[dashed] (-30:4.6) arc(-30:-120:4.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{}; 
            \draw[dashed] (-60:5.0) arc(-60:-150:5.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{};
            \draw[dashed] (-90:5.4) arc(-90:-180:5.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{};
            %\draw[|-|] (-120:5.0) arc(-120:-210:5.0) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_86$};
            \draw[|-|] (-150:5.8) arc(-150:-240:5.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-\frac{l}{n}-2}$};        
            \draw[|-|] (-180:6.2) arc(-180:-270:6.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-\frac{l}{n}-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-210:6.6) arc(-210:-300:6.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-\frac{l}{n}}$}; 
            %\draw[|-|] (-240:5.2) arc(-240:-330:5.2) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_{12}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

and the second `tikz` picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
            
            % inner arcs
            \draw[|-|] (135:2.2) arc(135:45.0:2.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (112.5:1.6) arc(112.5:22.5:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.0) arc(90.0:00.0:1.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:00.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:4.4) arc(67.5:-22.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:4.8) arc(45.0:-45.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (180.0:4.8) arc(180.0:90.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (202.5:4.4) arc(202.5:112.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (225.0:4.0) arc(225.0:135.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
            
            % upper dash
            \draw[dashed] (80:4.8) arc(80:60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (102.5:4.4) arc(102.5:82.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (125.0:4.0) arc(125.0:105.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            %% down dash
            
            % inner down dash
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.0) arc(240:260:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285.0:4.0) arc(285.0:305.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (325:4.0) arc(325:345:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % midle down dash
            \draw[dashed] (215:4.4) arc(215:235:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (260:4.4) arc(260:280:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (305:4.4) arc(305:325:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % outer down dash
            \draw[dashed] (195:4.8) arc(195:215:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.8) arc(240:260:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285:4.8) arc(285:305:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to put the two `tikz` pictures into a single `frame` of a `beamer` like this.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=9cm},
        arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
        ]
        
        \node[expl, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30]  % <- add options here (or at the other node)
        (rhootext)
        at (5.5,-3.0cm)
        {\draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
            
            % inner arcs
            \draw[|-|] (135:2.2) arc(135:45.0:2.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (112.5:1.6) arc(112.5:22.5:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.0) arc(90.0:00.0:1.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:00.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:4.4) arc(67.5:-22.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:4.8) arc(45.0:-45.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (180.0:4.8) arc(180.0:90.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (202.5:4.4) arc(202.5:112.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (225.0:4.0) arc(225.0:135.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
            
            % upper dash
            \draw[dashed] (80:4.8) arc(80:60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (102.5:4.4) arc(102.5:82.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (125.0:4.0) arc(125.0:105.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            %% down dash
            
            % inner down dash
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.0) arc(240:260:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285.0:4.0) arc(285.0:305.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (325:4.0) arc(325:345:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % midle down dash
            \draw[dashed] (215:4.4) arc(215:235:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (260:4.4) arc(260:280:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (305:4.4) arc(305:325:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % outer down dash
            \draw[dashed] (195:4.8) arc(195:215:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.8) arc(240:260:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285:4.8) arc(285:305:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };};
        
        \node[expl]
        (rhotext)
        at (14.5,-8.8cm)
        {\[
            \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
            \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col = 11]
                x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &     &     &     &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_1} \\
                & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 &     &     &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_2} \\
                &     &     & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &     &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_3} \\
                &     &     &     & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &     &      &        &  \mathbf{B_4} \\
                &     &     &     &     &     & x_7 & x_8 & x_9  &        &  \mathbf{B_5} \\
                &     &     &     &     &     &     & x_8 & x_9  & x_{10} &  \mathbf{B_6} \\
            \end{pNiceMatrix}
            \]};
        
        \draw[arrow]
        (rhootext.east) to[out=0,in=0]([yshift=0.5ex]{rhotext});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of the matrixes, I want to put the two tilz and the `tikz` arrow.

**What I Tried**
I tried this.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=9cm},
        arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
        ]
        
        \node[expl, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30]  % <- add options here (or at the other node)
        (rhootext)
        at (5.5,-3.0cm)
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
            
            % inner arcs
            \draw[|-|] (135:2.2) arc(135:45.0:2.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (112.5:1.6) arc(112.5:22.5:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.0) arc(90.0:00.0:1.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:00.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:4.4) arc(67.5:-22.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:4.8) arc(45.0:-45.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (180.0:4.8) arc(180.0:90.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (202.5:4.4) arc(202.5:112.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (225.0:4.0) arc(225.0:135.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
            
            % upper dash
            \draw[dashed] (80:4.8) arc(80:60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (102.5:4.4) arc(102.5:82.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (125.0:4.0) arc(125.0:105.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            %% down dash
            
            % inner down dash
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.0) arc(240:260:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285.0:4.0) arc(285.0:305.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (325:4.0) arc(325:345:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % midle down dash
            \draw[dashed] (215:4.4) arc(215:235:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (260:4.4) arc(260:280:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (305:4.4) arc(305:325:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % outer down dash
            \draw[dashed] (195:4.8) arc(195:215:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.8) arc(240:260:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285:4.8) arc(285:305:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        
        \node[expl]
        (rhotext)
        at (14.5,-8.8cm)
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
            \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
            
            % inner arcs
            \draw[|-|] (135:2.2) arc(135:45.0:2.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
            \draw[|-|] (112.5:1.6) arc(112.5:22.5:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
            \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.0) arc(90.0:00.0:1.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:00.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (67.5:4.4) arc(67.5:-22.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (45.0:4.8) arc(45.0:-45.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
            
            \draw[|-|] (180.0:4.8) arc(180.0:90.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (202.5:4.4) arc(202.5:112.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
            \draw[|-|] (225.0:4.0) arc(225.0:135.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
            
            % upper dash
            \draw[dashed] (80:4.8) arc(80:60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (102.5:4.4) arc(102.5:82.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (125.0:4.0) arc(125.0:105.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            %% down dash
            
            % inner down dash
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.0) arc(240:260:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285.0:4.0) arc(285.0:305.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (325:4.0) arc(325:345:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % midle down dash
            \draw[dashed] (215:4.4) arc(215:235:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (260:4.4) arc(260:280:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (305:4.4) arc(305:325:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            
            % outer down dash
            \draw[dashed] (195:4.8) arc(195:215:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (240:4.8) arc(240:260:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            \draw[dashed] (285:4.8) arc(285:305:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        
        \draw[arrow]
        (rhootext.east) to[out=0,in=0]([yshift=0.5ex]{rhotext});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the question exactly? You tried that and ...? Or you tried that but ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pic` https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics

But it is not a `node`, we cannot then find our way with the `.east` anchors for example. To avoid confusion I replace `rhootext` with `A` (a point) and `rhotext` with `B`.

What I learned from Qrrbrbirlbel's answer to this post [Tilted things in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693769/tilted-things-in-latex/693778#693778), we can see inside the pic with `coordinate()`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699171/put-two-tikz-pictures-in-adjacently-opposite-boxes-a-beamer
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=9cm},
    arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
    ]
\pic[expl, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30] (A) 
        {code=
            {
                \draw (5.5,-3.0) rectangle +(3,1) coordinate();
            }
        };
\pic[expl]  (B)
        {code=
            {
                \draw (14.5,-8.8) circle(1)coordinate();              
            }
        };
\draw[arrow] (A)+(0,-0.5) to[out=0,in=60]([shift=(60:1)]B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With your first picture (no empty line), with `\path(6,0) coordinate();`

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699171/put-two-tikz-pictures-in-adjacently-opposite-boxes-a-beamer
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    expl/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange!30,rounded corners,text width=9cm},
    arrow/.style={red!80!black,ultra thick,->,>=latex}
    ]
\pic[expl, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30] (A) 
        {code=
            {
        \path(6,0) coordinate();
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
        \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
        \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
        \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
        \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
        %
        % inner arcs
        \draw[|-|] (135:2.2) arc(135:45.0:2.2) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (112.5:1.6) arc(112.5:22.5:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.0) arc(90.0:00.0:1.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
        %
        \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:00.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (67.5:4.4) arc(67.5:-22.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (45.0:4.8) arc(45.0:-45.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
        %
        \draw[|-|] (180.0:4.8) arc(180.0:90.0:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (202.5:4.4) arc(202.5:112.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (225.0:4.0) arc(225.0:135.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
        %
        % upper dash
        \draw[dashed] (80:4.8) arc(80:60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (102.5:4.4) arc(102.5:82.5:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (125.0:4.0) arc(125.0:105.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        %
        %% down dash
        %
        % inner down dash
        \draw[dashed] (240:4.0) arc(240:260:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (285.0:4.0) arc(285.0:305.0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (325:4.0) arc(325:345:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        %
        % midle down dash
        \draw[dashed] (215:4.4) arc(215:235:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (260:4.4) arc(260:280:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (305:4.4) arc(305:325:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        %
        % outer down dash
        \draw[dashed] (195:4.8) arc(195:215:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (240:4.8) arc(240:260:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
        \draw[dashed] (285:4.8) arc(285:305:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{ };
            }
        };
\pic[expl]  (B)
        {code=
            {
                \draw (14.5,-8.8) circle(1)coordinate();              
            }
        };
\draw[arrow] (A)+(0,-0.5) to[out=0,in=60]([shift=(60:1)]B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]